Cause of abnormal laptop shutdown? Could ACPI Errors cause Overheating?
My well cooled laptop surprisingly shutdown at about 5 am local time, when I was sleeping. If anyone could help me decipher from logs or whatever below, what was the real cause, I would appreciate it very much. I attach some minimalistic hw info + log.
Yeah, I saw critical temperature in the log, but it has to be mistake or something. My laptop never overheats... Well, let's suppose it has been caused by overheating, for the sake of argument, what could have caused it? Could those ACPI Errors cause Overheating? The laptop had no reason to overheat, now exactly same VPN+torrents are running, and this is what sensors show:
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +50.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Processor Fan:    0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 4900 RPM)
Video Fan:        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 4900 RPM)
CPU:            +54.0°C  
Ambient:        +51.0°C  
SODIMM:         +38.0°C  
Other:          +47.0°C  
GPU:            +52.0°C  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max =  +5.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          17.34 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +47.0°C  

nvme-pci-3d00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +35.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +84.8°C)
                       (crit = +94.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +35.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 8:     +35.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  

The only thigs that were running: de Cinnamon, vpn with its gui, and Transmission torrent client downloading stuff to my NAS (NFSv4.1).
My laptop is Dell 7577 (cpu i7-7700hq, ram 32gb ddr4, ssd sata samsung), kernel 6.8.0-45-generic, Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon (64bit, uefi):
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Starting dpkg-db-backup.service - Daily dpkg database backup service...
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Starting logrotate.service - Rotate log files...
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Stopping cups-browsed.service - Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: cups-browsed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Stopped cups-browsed.service - Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Stopping cups.service - CUPS Scheduler...
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: cups.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Stopped cups.service - CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: cups.path: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Stopped cups.path - CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Stopping cups.path - CUPS Scheduler...
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Started cups.path - CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: cups.socket: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Closed cups.socket - CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Stopping cups.socket - CUPS Scheduler...
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Listening on cups.socket - CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Starting cups.service - CUPS Scheduler...
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Started cups.service - CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Started cups-browsed.service - Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Finished logrotate.service - Rotate log files.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: dpkg-db-backup.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:00:01 systemd[1]: Finished dpkg-db-backup.service - Daily dpkg database backup service.
Oct 09 00:00:01 CRON[25718]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 00:00:01 CRON[25719]: (root) CMD (timeshift --check --scripted)
Oct 09 00:00:02 crontab[25746]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 00:00:02 crontab[25747]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 00:00:02 systemd[1]: run-timeshift-25719-backup.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:00:02 CRON[25718]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 00:12:11 kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3931 > 3925), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
Oct 09 00:17:01 CRON[25829]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 00:17:01 CRON[25830]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 09 00:17:01 CRON[25829]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 00:24:01 CRON[25861]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 00:24:01 CRON[25862]: (root) CMD (if [ $(date +%w) -eq 0 ] && [ -x /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub ]; then /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub; fi)
Oct 09 00:24:01 CRON[25861]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 00:26:01 systemd[1]: Starting fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Oct 09 00:26:01 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 00:26:01 systemd[1]: Finished fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Oct 09 01:00:01 CRON[26037]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 01:00:01 CRON[26038]: (root) CMD (timeshift --check --scripted)
Oct 09 01:00:01 crontab[26065]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 01:00:01 crontab[26066]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 01:00:01 systemd[1]: run-timeshift-26038-backup.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 01:00:01 CRON[26037]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 01:17:01 CRON[26141]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 01:17:01 CRON[26142]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 09 01:17:01 CRON[26141]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 01:26:01 systemd[1]: Starting fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Oct 09 01:26:01 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 01:26:01 systemd[1]: Finished fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Oct 09 01:43:41 systemd[1]: Starting motd-news.service - Message of the Day...
Oct 09 01:43:41 systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 01:43:41 systemd[1]: Finished motd-news.service - Message of the Day.
Oct 09 02:00:01 CRON[26362]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 02:00:01 CRON[26363]: (root) CMD (timeshift --check --scripted)
Oct 09 02:00:01 crontab[26390]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 02:00:01 crontab[26391]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 02:00:01 systemd[1]: run-timeshift-26363-backup.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 02:00:01 CRON[26362]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 02:17:01 CRON[26466]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 02:17:01 CRON[26467]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 09 02:17:01 CRON[26466]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 02:41:01 systemd[1]: Starting fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Oct 09 02:41:01 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 02:41:01 systemd[1]: Finished fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Oct 09 03:00:01 CRON[26682]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 03:00:01 CRON[26683]: (root) CMD (timeshift --check --scripted)
Oct 09 03:00:02 crontab[26710]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 03:00:02 crontab[26711]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 03:00:02 systemd[1]: run-timeshift-26683-backup.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 03:00:02 CRON[26682]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 03:10:01 CRON[26756]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 03:10:01 CRON[26757]: (root) CMD (test -e /run/systemd/system || SERVICE_MODE=1 /sbin/e2scrub_all -A -r)
Oct 09 03:10:01 CRON[26756]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 03:17:01 CRON[26787]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 03:17:01 CRON[26788]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 09 03:17:01 CRON[26787]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 03:54:10 systemd[1]: Starting fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Oct 09 03:54:10 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 03:54:10 systemd[1]: Finished fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Oct 09 04:00:01 CRON[27006]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 04:00:01 CRON[27007]: (root) CMD (timeshift --check --scripted)
Oct 09 04:00:01 crontab[27034]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 04:00:01 crontab[27035]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 04:00:01 systemd[1]: run-timeshift-27007-backup.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 04:00:01 CRON[27006]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 04:17:01 CRON[27109]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 04:17:01 CRON[27110]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 09 04:17:01 CRON[27109]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 04:23:01 systemd[1]: Starting fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Oct 09 04:23:01 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 04:23:01 systemd[1]: Finished fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Oct 09 05:00:01 CRON[27304]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Oct 09 05:00:01 CRON[27305]: (root) CMD (timeshift --check --scripted)
Oct 09 05:00:01 crontab[27332]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 05:00:01 crontab[27333]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 09 05:00:01 systemd[1]: run-timeshift-27305-backup.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 05:00:01 CRON[27304]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 09 05:08:31 systemd[1]: Starting plocate-updatedb.service - Update the plocate database...
Oct 09 05:10:46 systemd[1]: plocate-updatedb.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 09 05:10:46 systemd[1]: Finished plocate-updatedb.service - Update the plocate database.
Oct 09 05:10:46 systemd[1]: plocate-updatedb.service: Consumed 1min 24.335s CPU time.
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-296)
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-306)
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: 
                        Initialized Local Variables for Method [ECR1]:
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel:   Local0: 000000007eb1c076 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECR1]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel:   Arg0:   00000000465187ee <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000034
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.ECR1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.KDRT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:12:59 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.SEN3._TMP due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:12:59 thermald[1024]: critical temp reached
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-296)
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-306)
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [ECW1]
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECW1]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel:   Arg0:   0000000010177d08 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000033
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel:   Arg1:   000000004a48fdbe <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.ECW1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.KDRT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:01 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.SEN2._TMP due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-296)
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-306)
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [ECW1]
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECW1]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel:   Arg0:   0000000053ba8808 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000033
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel:   Arg1:   00000000a9c7eac9 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.ECW1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.KDRT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:04 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.TMEM._TMP due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:06 thermald[1024]: critical temp reached
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-296)
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-306)
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [ECW1]
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECW1]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel:   Arg0:   00000000ecd5f192 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000033
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel:   Arg1:   00000000edf1d9c2 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: 
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.ECW1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV.KDRT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Oct 09 05:13:06 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.B0D4._TMP due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)



My well cooled laptop

I thought that was an odd way to start, until I saw the event at 5:12 in your logs:
Oct 09 05:12:59 thermald[1024]: critical temp reached

Critical temperature is critical temperature.  If your laptop appears to be well-cooled from the outside, then it's probably a good idea to dismantle whatever you can and dust it.  Compressed air in the vents helps.  Even if you suspend your laptop over an air-conditioning outlet, if that cool air doesn't reach a critical component or heat-sink, you'll have a problem.
Using a tool like sensors can help to monitor temperatures of whatever your mobo supports (CPU, memory, south bridge, GPU, disks).
Example:
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +31.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +31.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +31.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +31.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  
temp2:        +29.8°C  

nct6795-isa-0a20
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:                 776.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                     1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:                    3.41 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:                   3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:                     1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                   144.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                     1.27 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:                    3.39 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:                    2.96 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in9:                   992.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                    1.27 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                    0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
in12:                  992.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                  680.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                    1.53 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                   969 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                   797 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                 +27.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
CPUTIN:                 +24.0°C  (high = +115.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                +12.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                +12.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:               -128.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                 -2.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0:           +31.5°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
PCH_MCH_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
Agent0 Dimm0:            +0.0°C  
intrusion0:            ALARM
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +31.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +31.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +32.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C


Usually, it's dust.

I suspect those are a consequence rather than a cause.

No, my laptop now does the same things and the temperatures are ok, see update. I value your time, but you are focusing on wrong places, instead of researching what triggered the overheating, you are just stating it overheated...
